# Make a uniqueidentifier column not null using 'select insert' statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to insert data from one table into another using the 'select into' statement like in the example code.

I need the uniqueidentifier column `Id` to be `NOT NULL` in `TestTable`, but it's not working.

I read that using the function 'ISNULL()' would be the way to go.
It works with the column `Value`.

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(ID, NEWID()) AS [Id],
    ISNULL([Value], 'TestText') AS [Value]
INTO 
    [TestTable] 
FROM
    [Source]
```

Example for the source table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Source]
(
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Value] nvarchar(100) NULL
)
```

Result in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

Any idea about why this is happening or how I can achieve my goal?
I tried it with SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Can you provide the definitions for both tables? ISNULL will select the latter value if the first value provided is NULL. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Based on your explanation, it also appears that you are missing a FROM clause in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `NEWID` not `ISNULL`. When defining a column with `INTO` the column is defined as nullable if the expression that defined it is nullable. For `ISNULL` the expression is nullable if the both expressions can return `NULL`; `NEWID` is defined as nullable so `ISNULL(NEWID(),NEWID())` is nullable too.

A non-`NULL` literal is never Nullable, so provide a valid `uniqueidentifier` instead:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(NEWID(),'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') AS ID,
       'Test' AS Value
INTO dbo.test;
GO

SELECT name, is_nullable
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.test');
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.test;
```